# How do namespace's with same name but different scope (e.g. foo, bar::foo) work?

Tags: c++, namespaces

If there are two namespaces named `Foo` and `Bar` and there is a namespace named `Foo` inside `Bar`. If I refer to a variable `Foo::i` from inside `Bar` will it search for `i` in both `Foo` and `Bar::Foo`. If not, is it possible to make the compiler search in both namespaces when `i` doesn't exist in `Bar::Foo`?

More concrentely in the below example, I am trying to refer variable `i` from namespace a in b without puting extra `::`. I know putting `::` works, I am trying to see if there is any other way to resolve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace a {
    int i = 1;
}

namespace b {
    namespace a {
    }
    
    namespace c {
        int j = a::i; // Doesn't work, need to use ::a::i;
    }
}
int main()
{
  std::cout << b::c::j << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change `b::a`, then you can indeed make certain declarations available in `b::a` from `::a` as fallbacks:

```
namespace a {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
}

namespace b {
    namespace a {
        namespace detail {
            using ::a::i; // Selectively bring declarations from ::a here
        }
        using namespace detail; // Make the names in detail available for lookup (but not as declarations).
        //int i = 2;
    }
    
    namespace c {
        int j = a::i; // Uses ::a::i
        // int k = a::j; // ERROR! We didn't bring ::a::j into b::a at all
    }
}
```

[Here it is live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MlqASQtbl4CRUcf9).

Un-commenting the declaration of `b::a::i` will change the output. Since a proper declaration takes precedence over names brought in by a namespace using directive.

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly have a `using` declaration in the inner namespace for variables that it wants to use from the outer one.
i.e. for your example,

```
namespace a {
    int i = 1;
}

namespace b {
    namespace a {
        using ::a::i; //inner one does not define its own
        int i2 = 2;   //inner one creates its own variable
    }

    namespace c {
        int j = a::i; // Doesn't work, need to use ::a::i;
    }
}
```

See:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations